# Troubles with start java application

Tags: java, deployment, tomcat

I'm trying start java application but in browser i see standard tomcat's page.

*Server Log*

```
cmd /c "E:\disk C\prg_plus\apache-tomcat-6.0.16\bin\catalina.bat" run
Using CATALINA_BASE:   C:\Documents and Settings\compiler\.IntelliJIdea90\system\tomcat\Unnamed1_untitled1b081ac9b
Using CATALINA_HOME:   E:\disk C\prg_plus\apache-tomcat-6.0.16
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: E:\disk C\prg_plus\apache-tomcat-6.0.16\temp
Using JRE_HOME:        C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_10
26.07.2010 20:25:36 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_10\bin;.;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files\Ruby19\bin;C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Bin;C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Projects\Bpl\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Adobe\AGL;c:\program files\jetbrains\intellij idea 9.0.2\jre\jre\bin
26.07.2010 20:25:36 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
26.07.2010 20:25:36 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1789 ms
26.07.2010 20:25:36 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
26.07.2010 20:25:36 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.16
26.07.2010 20:25:38 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext addApplicationListener
INFO: The listener "org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener" is already configured for this context. The duplicate definition has been ignored.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
26.07.2010 20:25:56 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext addApplicationListener
INFO: The listener "listeners.ContextListener" is already configured for this context. The duplicate definition has been ignored.
26.07.2010 20:25:56 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext addApplicationListener
INFO: The listener "listeners.SessionListener" is already configured for this context. The duplicate definition has been ignored.
26.07.2010 20:25:56 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
26.07.2010 20:25:57 org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
26.07.2010 20:25:57 org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/141  config=null
26.07.2010 20:25:57 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 20809 ms
Connected to server
```

*Tomcat Log*

```
26.07.2010 20:25:39 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
26.07.2010 20:25:53 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter INFO: loaded (conf ok)
26.07.2010 20:25:54 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
26.07.2010 20:25:56 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
26.07.2010 20:25:56 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
```

Jar's

```
activation-1.1.jar
antlr-2.7.6.jar
antlr.jar
aopalliance.jar
asm.jar
cglib.jar
commons-collections-3.1.jar
commons-collections.jar
commons-dbcp.jar
commons-logging.jar
commons-pool.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
geronimo-validation_1.0_spec-1.0-CR5(2).jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
hibernate-validator-4.0.2.GA.jar
hibernate3.jar
javassist-3.9.0.GA.jar
jaxb-api-2.1.jar
jaxb-impl-2.1.3.jar
jpa-api-2.0.Beta-20090815.jar
jta-1.1.jar
jta.jar
log4j-1.2.15.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.7-bin.jar
org.springframework.aop-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.aspects-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.beans-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.context-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.context.support-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.jdbc-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.jms-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.orm-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.transaction-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web.portlet-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
persistence-api-1.0.2.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar
spring-asm-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-instrument-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-oxm-3.0.3.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-oxm-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
stax-api-1.0-2.jar
urlrewrite-3.2.0.jar
validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
```

What I do wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with Spring or Hibernate, it's a more basic problem of deploying your webapp under the correct path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What context path is the application deployed under?

If you built a war file named `application.war`, and deployed it by simply copying it to the `webapps/` folder, then Tomcat deploys it as `/application` - meaning you would have to request `http://hostname:port/application` to access it.

It sounds like you are merely visiting `http://hostname:port/`.